# key :variable_name not found in

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

After config my project following the Github documentation https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view, I received this error, and I don't know what I did wrong.

Complete project: https://github.com/ruannawe/live_view_counter

```
defmodule CounterWeb.CounterLive do
    use Phoenix.LiveView

    def mount(_session, socket) do
        blabla = 0
        socket = assign(socket, :variable_name, blabla)
        {:ok, socket}
    end

    def render(assigns) do
        ~L"""
        <h1>Count: <%= @variable_name %></h1>
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
        """
    end
end
```

The error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the params argument in your mount function, which is causing the assigns map to be empty because your mount/2 is never pattern matched, prepending it fixes the issue;

```
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
          ^^^^^^^
  blabla = 0
  socket = assign(socket, :variable_name, blabla)
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

I haven't tested the referred Github snippet, perhaps this behaviour has changed, but not that I am aware of.

Comment: Thank you Hedde!

Put @impl true on top of callbacks and you get a warning in case of an argument mismatch.

Jose Valim gave me this advice:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/issues/2467